# Automatic User Creation for SSH Server?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I'm trying to setup an SSH server which, upon an attempted connection with the correct public key, will create a new user account if one does not exist.

On connection I'd like a specific script to run for that user, which upon exiting, would disconnect them.

The point of this is to have a server which will run a specified script for whoever connects, but with their own account for small save-files.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.10 with only a CLI.

I'm not particularly worried about security for the machine in-so-much as it will only be used for games, and contains no personal details of my own.

EDIT: While I feel this question would still be useful if answered in its original form, I have found a work-around that suits me for now: Instead of having ssh do all the work of setting up users on the fly, you can set one user to be accessible via ssh, and that user's launch script can be one which manages user accounts, creating them as needed, and then connecting the user to the correct file directory system for their "account".

Comment: A few ideas: http://superuser.com/a/603099/334516

Comment: "with the correct public key" - about which key are you talking?

Comment: @guntbert If you have ever played a rogue-like or such through an ssh client, you usually have to copy the public_key from the server's website (or ftp) and then send a command like: 
ssh -C -i cbro_key -l crawler http://crawl.berotato.org/

where cbro_key is the public_key

Comment: @muru That is quite interesting, and is pretty close to what I'm after. My issue is my lack of understanding of SSH, however, and figuring out how to have users require a public_key (and possibly generate a private_key to pair it with?) without manually creating a new user and then adding the RSA to their account.

Oh, and I still would have no clue how to configure which script to auto-start for them, assuming it's being done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work-around that suits me for now: Instead of having ssh do all the work of setting up users on the fly: you can set one user to be accessible via ssh:

edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` adding a line `'AllowUser <username here>'`

and that user's launch script can be one which manages user accounts, creating them as needed, and then connecting the user to the correct file directory system for their "account".

To set a script to run for a specific user connecting via SSH:

edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` adding the lines:

```
Match user username
    ForceCommand /path/to/script
```

Where the username is the one you would like to force the command on.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, have one user to create accounts, give him a public key, then instead of giving him a /bin/bash to login, you could give him a script, which would create a user and then after executing the script would quit the connection.

It should be possible to create a text file, where you would put the information into and type the username and password, just like you would on the console.

Textfile like so

```
jim <return>
a3drtZdf <return>
```

and the script has maybe a  `read -p "username" $USER`  and a `read -p password $PASS` and then would use these values in the script to do an `adduser -u $USER -p $PASS`

Not sure if it will work but actually it should. I did something similar, but not the same exact thing.

So in the end you would do

```
ssh useradd@example.com < values.txt -i id_rsa_useradd
```

The script will catch the input and executes it and then quits.